# Select Max Access Query - row max for column with WHERE criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

Microsoft Access 2010

I'm trying to get the Max visit number of a user within a sequence of visits less than or equal to 13 months apart.
So the last visit that was within a sequence of visits less than or equal to 13 months apart. I want to exclude those who only occasionally use it (ie. over 13 months apart)

I'm using this to run my query:

```
   SELECT  ID, AppointmentDate, Visit
FROM tblVisitQuestions t1
WHERE t1.Visit = 
    (SELECT Max(t2.Visit)
     FROM tblVisitQuestions t2 
     WHERE t2.ID=t1.ID AND (DateDiff("m",[t1].[AppointmentDate],[t2].[AppointmentDate]) <= 13) 
     GROUP BY t2.ID)
```

Its working except that its returning multiple values for the same ID number.
Not sure if its an error within my data or my query.

Ex: example data in table

```
CR  AppointmentDate Visit
1   15-Apr-05       0
1   15-Jul-05       1
1   16-May-06       2
1   06-Jun-06       3
1   19-Dec-06       4
1   11-Nov-11       5
1   31-Jan-12       6
2   08-Jun-04       0
2   17-Dec-04       1
2   05-Jul-05       2
2   06-Dec-05       3
2   06-Feb-09       4
2   19-Apr-11       5
```

what I would like after the query (not what I'm getting now)

```
CR  AppointmentDate Visit
1   19-Dec-06       4
2   06-Dec-05       3
```

what I am actually getting:

```
CR  AppointmentDate Visit
1   19-Dec-06       4
1   31-Jan-12       6
2   06-Feb-09       4
2   19-Apr-11       5
```

**I need a way to select the min value of the max values I am getting**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you *are* getting?

Comment: Just added some better examples hopefully

Answer (score 1):

For each visit, you can get the maximum visit number in the 13 months afterwards by doing:

```
SELECT ID, AppointmentDate, Visit,
       (SELECT Max(t2.Visit)
        FROM tblVisitQuestions as t2 
        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND (DateDiff("m",[t1].[AppointmentDate],[t2].[AppointmentDate]) <= 13) 
       ) as MaxVisit
FROM tblVisitQuestions as t1;
```

If you want this only where the visit number is one, then add a where clause:

```
WHERE t1.Visit = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to then select the Min value of MaxVisit?

Could I use `Select Min` on the MaxVisit?

Comment: As in Query on the subquery within the orginal query or should I do this in two separate queries?

Comment: @Victoria . . . You can always use a subquery.